# Find specific text in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this VBA for excel, anyway I'm trying to write some code that will iterate through the dataset until it comes to a specific text, in my example I'm looking to find the name "FRANKS" so I wrote some code which does that and it works, now I'm trying to figure out how to stop on that cell, copy it and append it to the cell next to it. Long story short, I have a report that runs every week and when certain employees names get split(text to columns) some names don't come out right. So I have to manually fix them. So here I am trying to automate it.
Below is the code I have written so far.

```
      row_number = 0

 Do
 DoEvents
 row_number = row_number + 1
 namedperson = Range("C" & row_number)
 Loop Until namedperson = "FRANKS"
 Columns("C & row_number").Activate
```

the last line doesn't work but you get the idea of what I'm trying to do.
Anyway after I grab this name "FRANKS" the column to the left of it is where I need to append the "FRANKS" to.....

Thanks in advance,
Lenny

Comment: First, declare your variables.  (In fact, stick `Option Explicit` at the start of the Module, so that Excel *forces* you to do this)  Second, why are you trying to find a row number in a column letter?  Should that be `Range("C" & row_number).Activate` instead?  This makes the cell to the left `Range("B" & row_number)`, so set the `.value` property

Comment: if you want to stop the `Do` loop at the first time the conditions are met use `exit do`

Answer (score 2):

No need for loops.

```
Dim i As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change to your sheet
    On Error Resume Next
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Franks", .Range("C:C"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If i <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Franks found at " & .Cells(i, 3).Address(0, 0)
    Else
        MsgBox "Franks not found in Column"
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim StringToSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range

    StringToSearch = "FRANK"

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3) '<~~ Change as applicable
        Set aCell = .Find(What:=StringToSearch, _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=False)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Found at " & aCell.Address
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

For a partial search for example `Frank` in `frankenstein`, change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart`

and

For Case Sensitive search change `MatchCase:=False` to `MatchCase:=True`

Comment: How can I overwrite `acell`? `acell.value="foo"` does not work: `object needed`

Comment: Replace `MsgBox "Found at " & aCell.Address` with `acell.value="foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

Looping until you find a certain value is not a good idea if the value doesn't exist. I would suggest looping through your range, and if you find the value, append it to the cell to the left. You didn't say whether you wanted to stop at the first occurrence of "FRANKS", so my code keeps going in case there are multiple. There are different ways to refer to a cell, but this should give you the idea.

```
row_count = 7  ' the number of rows in your range
For r = 1 To row_count
    If Cells(r, 3) = "FRANKS" Then
        Cells(r, 2) = Cells(r, 2) & "FRANKS"
    End If
Next r
```